# Расширение значений на основе DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

В результате группировки по столбцу `df['Date']` получается `DataFrame`, сгруппированный по дню. Но если какого-то дня нет в столбце `df['Date']`, то и строки с такими данными нет. Вопрос - как создать `DataFrame` со столбцом всех дней, и заполнить этот `DataFrame` на основе сгруппированных значений таким образом, чтобы в отсутствующие дни в изначальном столбце стояли `NaN` значения, а остальные были заполнены.

Пример:

```
+------------+------+
|    Date    | Col2 |
+------------+------+
| 01.01.2019 |    1 |
| 03.01.2019 |    2 |
+------------+------+
```

А нужна такая таблица:

```
+------------+------+
|    Date    | Col2 |
+------------+------+
| 01.01.2019 | 1    |
| 02.01.2019 | NaN  |
| 03.01.2019 | 2    |
| 04.01.2019 | NaN  |
| .......    |      |
+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте сначала задал фрейм с диапазоном нужных дат, а затем "слил" бы в него ваши данные:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01.01.2019', '02.01.2019', '13.01.2019'], 'Col2': [1, 2, 13]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Исходный фрейм

```
            Col2
Date            
2019-01-01     1
2019-01-02     2
2019-01-13    13
```

Ну а затем:

```
start_date='01.01.2019'
end_date = '15.01.2019'
days = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(start_date, dayfirst = True), end=pd.to_datetime(end_date, dayfirst = True), freq="D", )
res = pd.DataFrame(index=days)
res.join(df)
```

И на выходе:

```
            Col2
2019-01-01  1.0
2019-01-02  2.0
2019-01-03  NaN
2019-01-04  NaN
2019-01-05  NaN
2019-01-06  NaN
2019-01-07  NaN
2019-01-08  NaN
2019-01-09  NaN
2019-01-10  NaN
2019-01-11  NaN
2019-01-12  NaN
2019-01-13  13.0
2019-01-14  NaN
2019-01-15  NaN
```

Comment: Вопрос, а как публиковать `DataFrame` для примера в формате, как у вас?

Comment: @Ratatuy129, проще всего воспользоваться [iPython](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) - скопировать вывод в буфер обмена и вставить в вопросе/ответе SO...

Comment: @Ratatuy129 я бы вообще рекомендовал вам `jupyter notebook` - удобный фреймворк, и так же можно копировать вывод и вставлять в вопрос.

Comment: @strawdog, не знал что в новых версиях Jupyter появилась возможность копировать вывод в виде текста - раньше мне этого сильно не хватало)

Answer (score 3):

Я бы в данном случае воспользовался методом [DataFrame.reindex(index)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
dt_start = "2019-01-01"
N = 31
dt_end = "2019-01-31"

df = (pd.DataFrame(
            np.random.randint(10, size=(31, 3)), 
            columns=list("abc"), 
            index=pd.date_range(dt_start, periods=N))
        .sample(frac=0.5)
        .sort_index())
```

---

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
            a  b  c
2019-01-02  8  5  4
2019-01-03  4  5  3
2019-01-06  6  4  4
2019-01-08  9  8  0
2019-01-12  5  8  5
2019-01-13  7  7  6
2019-01-14  3  8  8
...        .. .. ..
2019-01-19  4  1  8
2019-01-20  6  1  7
2019-01-21  7  0  4
2019-01-22  3  2  9
2019-01-24  5  2  3
2019-01-26  6  2  7
2019-01-30  5  8  6

[16 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

создаем индекс без пропусков:

```
idx = pd.date_range(dt_start, dt_end)
```

переиндексируем DF используя созданный индекс:

```
df = df.reindex(idx)
```

результат:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
              a    b    c
2019-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-02  8.0  5.0  4.0
2019-01-03  4.0  5.0  3.0
2019-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-05  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-06  6.0  4.0  4.0
2019-01-07  NaN  NaN  NaN
...         ...  ...  ...
2019-01-25  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-26  6.0  2.0  7.0
2019-01-27  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-28  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-29  NaN  NaN  NaN
2019-01-30  5.0  8.0  6.0
2019-01-31  NaN  NaN  NaN

[31 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

этот метод можно объединить с группировкой:

```
idx = pd.date_range(dt_start, dt_end)
res = df.groupby("Date").agg(...).reindex(idx)
```